# How to load a *.qgs file in a C++ QGIS standalone app?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, c++

I'm using QGIS-2.4.0 API to develop a standalone app by C++.

I saved a test.qgs file in QGIS Desktop software, in the project, there was one layer and it was visible.

Then I loaded the test.qgs project file in app, but there is nothing showed.

Why is that?

The code I'm using to open the project is:

```
QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);
QString myQgisDir = "C:\\Program Files(x86)\\qgis2.4.0";
app.setPrefixPath(myQgisDir, true);
app.initQgis();

//The set of mapcavas
QgsMapCanvass *myMapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas();
myMapCanvas->enableAntiAliasing(true);
myMapCanvas->setCanvasColor(Qt::white);
myMapCanvas->setVisiable(true);

//Open *.qgs project and read
QString myProjectPath = "E:\\QGIS\\Pro\\test.qgs"; 
Qgsproject::instance()->setFileName(myProjectPath); 
bool isRead = QgsProject::instance()->read();    //In Debug mode, isRead equals TRUE.
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: may you try to do QgsProject::instance()->clear() before read the new project?

Comment: @LuigiPirelli I tried it and still nothing happened. I'm thinking if read() function is enough to load the project file, or it is needed other functions to complete the loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved by Matthias Kuhn, see [Here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/How-to-load-a-qgs-file-in-a-C-QGIS-standalone-app-td5169813.html#a5169838).

```
QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge should help you there 

header: 
QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge* mLayerTreeCanvasBridge; 

source: 
mLayerTreeCanvasBridge = new QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge( 
QgsProject::instance()->layerTreeRoot(), mMapCanvas, this ); 
QgsProject::instance()->read( path_to_your_project_file );
```